# Displaying a user picture in a Sharepoint web part

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have this code in a webpart in sharepoint foundation and it display user information, but now i need to display a user picture and i don´t know how to do it....i´m quite new to programming
Thanks in advance

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
var currentUser;
function init(){
    this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.oWeb = clientContext.get_web();
    currentUser = this.oWeb.get_currentUser();
    this.clientContext.load(currentUser);
    this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    document.getElementById('userLoginName').innerHTML = currentUser.get_loginName(); 
    document.getElementById('userTitle').innerHTML = currentUser.get_title();
    document.getElementById('userEmail').innerHTML = currentUser.get_email();


    
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>

<div>Current User: 
    <span id="userLoginName"></span></br>
</div>
<div>Username:
    <span id="userTitle"></span></br>
</div>
<div>Email:
    <span id="userEmail"></span></br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `getCurrentUser` method does not include any picture info.
You can refer to MSDN for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245893.aspx

Instead you need to get this information from the `User Profile Service`

You can get the current user id using a built-in SharePoint variable: `_spPageContextInfo.userId`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProfileImage,'sp.js');

var CamlResult;
function getUserProfileImage(){
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    var userInfoList = web.get_siteUserInfoList();
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

    var userID = _spPageContextInfo.userId;

    // define the query to retrieve the given user's details
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="ID"/><Value Type="Number">' + userID + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');

    CamlResult = userInfoList.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(CamlResult);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args){
    var profile, title, login, email, pic, picUrl;

    // There should be only result. Get the item at index 0
    profile = CamlResult.itemAt(0); 

    // read all the properties out

    title = profile.get_item('Title');
    login = profile.get_item("Name");
    email = profile.get_item("EMail");
    pic = profile.get_item('Picture');

    if (pic) { 
        picUrl = pic.get_url();
    } 

    // Setup HTML
    document.getElementById('userLoginName').innerHTML = login;
    document.getElementById('userTitle').innerHTML = title;
    document.getElementById('userEmail').innerHTML = email;

    if (picUrl) {
        // create the image
        imgMyPicture = document.createElement('img');
        imgMyPicture.src = '/sites/bms/bms/styles/img/OvalMenuImages/processes.png';
        imgMyPicture.setAttribute('title', 'Image from Current User's Profile');
        imgMyPicture.setAttribute('alt', 'Profile Picture');

        // append the image
        document.getElementById('userPicture').appendChild(iconElement);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('userPicture').innerHTML = "No image found in user profile";
    }
}

</script>
<div>Current User: 
    <span id="userLoginName"></span></br>
</div>
<div>Username:
    <span id="userTitle"></span></br>
</div>
<div>Email:
    <span id="userEmail"></span></br>
</div>
<div>Picture:
    <span id="userPicture"></span></br>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Jason, This Didnt work for me do i need to make nay changes in the script for information to populate.?

Comment: @octopus What version of SharePoint are you using? Is your user profile service (ups) running and have you added pictures? UPS can be tricky to work with, so it might be worth creating a new question with your exact details...

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2013 and my UPS is Running and Sync is running actively?

Comment: @octopus One thing I have found with UPS is that it will only complete profiles for users that have visited your site. So if you're trying to retrieve details for other users it might not work. Like I said, you're best asking a new question with your exact details so that people can give you a more detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

The property you want is called PictureURL. I'd also suggest looking into [SPServices](https://spservices.codeplex.com/) for this kind of work in the future, it makes this much more routine.

Answer (score 0):

Use an html image tag and according to the user display the image that you need.

> `<img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">`